# getting values from html rules using Java

Tags: java, android, jquery, html

for example i will give a sample source code of Amazon.com site and this is my html rules.

```
<div id="result_25" class="fstRowGrid prod celwidget" name="B00IVPU786">
    <div class="image imageContainer">
        <a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00IVPU786" rel="nofollow noreferrer"><div class="imageBox">
    <img onload="viewCompleteImageLoaded(this, new Date().getTime(), 24, false);" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41SmukivM1L._AA160_.jpg"  class="productImage cfMarker" alt="Product Details" />
        </div></a>

<span class="lrg bold">Samsung Electronics 32GB EVO Micro SDHC with Adapter Upto 48MB/s Class 10 Memory Card (MB-MP32DA/AM)</span></a> </h3><ul class="rsltGridList grey">
```

i used the below code to get the data

```
Elements e = d.select("div[id=result_25]");

String firstURL = e.select("a").attr("href");
String secondURL = e.select("img").attr("src");
```

this is how i got two URL from this. But i want this "Samsung Electronics 32GB EVO Micro SDHC with Adapter Upto 48MB/s Class 10 Memory Card (MB-MP32DA/AM)" which is coming under span when i used `String name = e.select("span").attr(null);` i am getting error and when i used `String name = e.select("span").attr(class);` i am getting class name bld lrg as output. how can i do this.

Comment: so you just want to get the text inside the `<span class="lrg bold">`?

Comment: yes i just want that ..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
e.select("span").html();
```

or

```
e.select("span").text();
```

Comment: Samsung Electronics 32GB EVO Micro SDHC with Adapter Upto 48MB/s Class 10 Memory Card (MB-MP32DA/AM) $19.73 Order in the next 32 hours and get it by Monday, Jul 21. 32 hours Monday, Jul 21 $14.69 (10 offers)       (417)
this is what i am getting when i use this. but i just want the name upto (MB-MP32DA/AM)

Comment: Document d=Jsoup.connect("http://www.amazon.com/b/?ie=UTF8&node=281407&page=2")
.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS i686 3912.101.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36").timeout(100000).get();
 Elements e = d.select("div[id=result_25]");

from the above URL and elements i want to get just <span class="lrg bold">Samsung Electronics 32GB EVO Micro SDHC with Adapter Upto 48MB/s Class 10 Memory Card (MB-MP32DA/AM)</span> value from this span class lrg bold

Comment: If it is a fixed format and this span will always have price after name you can use substring(). Or directly use the class "bld lrg" you are getting as output.

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
String value = e.select(".image .lrg").html();
```

Comment: still why would i get **$19.73** with the output

Comment: I don't know what **$19.73** is since your given code is not complete, can you tell me where does that come from?

Comment: also check the answer again, I edited it and let me know if that did anything!

Comment: I think the amazon site has some more rules with the above given one and the $19.73 is getting from that.. i am using this code to connect using jsoup and the below url is using 
Document d=Jsoup.connect("http://www.amazon.com/b/?ie=UTF8&node=281407&page=2")
.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS i686 3912.101.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36").timeout(100000).get();

Comment: Elements e = d.select("div[id=result_25]"); taking elements from this div id as well

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write code like that:

```
Elements e1 = d.select(".lrg bold");
String spantext=e1.text();
```

hope this help you..